# Get Process Infomation via pid in Win7

Tags: c, windows-7

I list process name in my program. First I use "EnumProcesses" to get all PID. Then I get Process name like this:

```
hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid );
if( hProcess ) {
    EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hModule, sizeof(hModule), NULL);
    GetModuleFileNameExW( hProcess, hModule, (LPWSTR)fileName, 100*sizeof(wchar_t) );

    printf ("[%d] 0x%08X %d - %ws \n", i, hProcess, pid, fileName);
}
```

I can get all Process in winxp. But, in Win7, Some Process's handle is NULL, So I cannot get its infomation. like this:

[image]

I do not know why. Who can tell me why? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either permissions (you need SEDebugPrivilege to enumerate all of them) or you're trying to enumerate 64 bit processes from a 32 bit process

Comment: If this was useful accept it as an answer (click the green "V" sign on the left of my answer)